# Root cannot save any file

Tags: 16.04, permissions, root, nano, editor

I tried editing any file with nano (sudo nano) and it just wont save. I tried with nginx configs, normal files, and crontab and they all wont save. I've also read this ([Cannot save any kind of file in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820409/cannot-save-any-kind-of-file-in-ubuntu)) and tried to fix it this way but it does not work for me.

Edit:
I'm signed in as root and files I want to edit are owned by root. I tried both Ctrl+O and then pressed Enter and Ctrl+X to exit and save, but both options are not working.

Comment: what error message do you get when you try to save the file? Can you give an example showing the exact commands you run and the exact errors/behaviour you are getting? Could the partition you are trying to edit files on be mounted read-only for some reason (is it an external drive or something? What is the output of `mount`?) or might there be some extended filesystem attributes?

Comment: @Zanna File I wanted to edit is /etc/nginx/sites-available/default (nginx config). I opened file with sudo nano ... and I'm able to change it, but when I try to save it it does not let me. It does not display any error but it does not let me save the file. Next I tried sudo crontab -e, then I entered some random cron job, tried to save the file, same thing. I overcame the problem with nginx config by logging into FTP (with root) and editing it that way. No problem there. So I only have problem when editing from terminal