# Unable to save files in Firefox, /tmp has become read-only after upgrade

Tags: firefox, 18.04, tmp

I recently upgraded to 18.04, and found out that when I tried to save files in Firefox I got an error saying that the "*could not be saved, because the disc, folder, or file is write-protected. Write-enable the disc and try again, or try saving in a different location*"

After doing some digging I discovered that /tmp had become read-only since the upgrade. Is there anything I can do?

I tried the answers outlined [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820409/cannot-save-any-kind-of-file-in-ubuntu), but none of them worked.

---

Output of `ls -ld /tmp` :

`drwxrwxrwt 21 root root 69632 Apr 28 12:10 /tmp`

---

Output of `mount | grep tmp`:

`udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3993816k,nr_inodes=998454,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=804648k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/user/128 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=804644k,mode=700,uid=128,gid=142)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=804644k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)`

---

Output of `df /tmp`:

`Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5       25087084 17130836   6658840  73% /`

---

Output of `mount | grep /dev/sda5`:

`/dev/sda5 on / type ext4 (ro,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)`

Comment: please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -ld /tmp`

Comment: I've added the requested info

Comment: These permissions are perfectly fine. Maybe Firefox is getting confined by some AppArmor profiles which are inappropriate in 18.04...

Comment: I'm not sure it's that. I tried creating a file using `touch` inside /tmp, and it wouldn't let me do so in a read-only file system. Can't `rm` /tmp either.

Comment: Can you add the output of `mount | grep /tmp` then?

Comment: Done. I also added the output of `df /tmp` as well.

Comment: Okay, so your `/tmp` is stored on the main partition. Is that one read-only? `mount | grep /dev/sda5`

Comment: Added that as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your "/" has been remounted to "ro" most likely due to "errors=remount-ro".  Check your /var/log/syslog and "smartctl -a ".

We had this happened to us once when the hard drive was on the brink of total failure.  You want to act quickly because it deteriorates very fast.

Comment: Also look in `dmesg`. I had this happen. There was a kernel message about an ext4 aborted journal.

Comment: Turned out it was close to failure. Accepted answer.